# JavaScript - How to retrieve new Index of class element after reordering using InsertBefore()

Tags: javascript, indexing

Note:  I do not know JQuery, only Vanilla JavaScript.

Good evening,

I cannot retrieve the updated Index of a class element after reordering the class element using the insertBefore() function.

Example:  Elements A, B, C with indexes 0, 1, 2 when rearranged:  C, A, B will have indexes 2, 0, 1 instead of 0, 1, 2.

Here is my code that I have used for testing.  You can click on the individual elements, the button reorder will move the last element before the first, and the index results can be viewed in the Console Log:

```js
let container = document.getElementById('container');

let items = document.querySelectorAll('.items');

items.forEach((row, index) => {
  row.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(index);
  });
});

let reorder = document.getElementById('reorder').addEventListener('click', () => {
  container.insertBefore(container.children[4], container.children[0]);
});
```

```css
#container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.items {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="items">0</div>
  <div class="items">1</div>
  <div class="items">2</div>
  <div class="items">3</div>
  <div class="items">4</div>

</div>

<button id="reorder">ReOrder</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution doesn't work as `index` is a part of a closure that is initially set when your `for` loop firsts adds the event listeners. You could find the index of the element you clicked on by searching for it amongst the [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) by using `.indexOf()`. You'll first need to convert the children to an array (this is done below using the [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) as it is a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which doesn't have an indexOf method:

```js
let container = document.getElementById('container');

let items = document.querySelectorAll('.items');

items.forEach((row, index) => {
  row.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    console.log([...container.children].indexOf(row));
  });
});

let reorder = document.getElementById('reorder').addEventListener('click', () => {
  container.insertBefore(container.children[4], container.children[0]);
});
```

```css
#container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.items {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="items">0</div>
  <div class="items">1</div>
  <div class="items">2</div>
  <div class="items">3</div>
  <div class="items">4</div>
</div>

<button id="reorder">ReOrder</button>
```

Comment: Thank You.  That worked perfectly, although I do not understand why it worked. I have never heard of the Spread Syntax.  I will have to review it in order to get an understanding of when and how to use it properly.  Again, thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: @GracialonIgnasiver no worries, the spread syntax is a very powerful tool and can be utilized in many places, so it's definitely worth looking into. If you feel as though this answer adequately answers your question you can consider accepting it by clicking the grey checkmark in the top left corner of the answer (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Oh, ok.  I clicked the arrow marking your answer as useful.  Sorry about that.  This is only my second time asking a question on this site.